# how to write a query to get distinct studentid

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

How to write a Linq query to get distinct students ids from a table based on months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you're looking for :

```
var ids = context.Students.Where(s => s.CreationDate.Month == 1 && s.CreationDate.Year == 2013).Select(s => s.Id).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: Hai thanks,but using  Ienumerable how to write this   IEnumerable<id> ids=
                db.Query<id>("").ToList();

Comment: It just works even with IEnumerable, otherwise just remove .ToList()

Comment: I wrote like this I am getting error IEnumerable< id> ids=
                db.Query< studentview>("Select distinct id from studentview where date between @1)",new DateTime(2013, 1, 1), newDateTime(2013, 1, 31)).ToList();

Answer (score 0):

Not testet but it should look something like this for a DataTable:

```
int year = 2013, month = 1;

var test = db.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<DateTime>("Date").Year == year && x.Field<DateTime>("Date").Month == month).GroupBy(y => y.Field<id>("ids")).Select(z => z.First());
```